# How to fix my listview Action Listener in Android Studios?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, actionlistener

I would like to set an action listener for my listview, such that specific details will be displayed depending on the position clicked. However I encountered an error in while using the getPosition() and getName() methods. Please help me remedy the situation, as well as explain how it functions as I'm confused.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter, View v, int position, long id) {

            String item = yourData.getPosition(position).getName(NAMES);

            Intent intentProduct = new Intent(Scrollable.this, ProductDetail.class);

            intentProduct.putExtra("Key", item);

            startActivity(intentProduct);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this**

```
String item = yourData.getPosition(position).getName();
```

**insted of**

```
String item = yourData.getPosition(position).getName(NAMES);
```

**code**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter, View v, int position, long id) {

            String item = yourData.getPosition(position).getName();

            Intent intentProduct = new Intent(Scrollable.this, ProductDetail.class);

            intentProduct.putExtra("Key", item);

            startActivity(intentProduct);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> String item = yourData.getPosition(position).getName(NAMES); //NAMES not nessasry

```html
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
            String item = yourData.getPosition(position).getName();
            Intent intentProduct = new Intent(Scrollable.this, ProductDetail.class);
            intentProduct.putExtra("Key", item);
           startActivity(intentProduct);
        }
    });
```